# Regex Readline to Count Tags

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a problem reading every line to count the regex of `<a href=`
when the regex been match it will skip the line and not finish till the end.  For example, here I have two `<a href` tags, but after reading the first one it will jump to the next line:

`"<p class="txt">Everyone seemed cool with that, including Coach A, so we went to work putting it all together. The end result had us starting off standing in a <strong>V formation</strong><a href="../Text/chap5.html#b1" id="f1">*</a>, and then the girls in back would tumble forward so that we were all in a straight line for the cheer. It was a really cool idea! To finish things off, we’d transition into two stunt groups that would do side-by-side <strong>elevators</strong><a href="../Text/chap5.html#b2" id="f2"></a>.</p>"`

Here is my code:

```
        Dim count1 As Integer = 0
        For p As Integer = 0 To lvw.Items.Count - 1
        Dim r As StreamReader = New StreamReader(New FileStream(Path.Combine(lvw.Items(p).Tag, lvw.Items(p).Text), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))

        Do While Not r.EndOfStream
            Dim strr1 As String = r.ReadLine.Trim
            Try
                Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("<a\s+[^>]*(href\s*=\s*(['""]).*?\2)")
                Dim m As Match = regex.Match(strr1)

                If m.Success Then
                    count1 += 1

                End If
                Label2.Text = (count1.ToString)
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        Loop

    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you required to use `ReadLine`?  You could use [`ReadToEnd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readtoend.aspx#Y0) to get the whole text at once, then use

```
regex.Matches(strr1).Count
```

to get the count of matches.

Comment: thank you i already resolve this I used  Dim strr1 As String = r.ReadLine.Trim
                Try
                    Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("<a\s+[^>]*(href\s*=\s*(['""]).*?\2)")
                    For Each m As Match In regex.Matches(strr1)
                        count1 += 1
                        'z += 1
                    Next